# Compare two timestamps in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I want to search a table if there which is invalid.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
DELETE FROM sessions WHERE validuntil < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

How can I do that and still use timestamps?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements for `sessions` and the error message you get or describe the unexpected behavior.

Comment: you will not get much help if you don't help people to help you, as sticky bit said, provide the CREATE TABLE statements and also which version you are using may help.  I know you do not mention it but are you also using PHP - this may provide alternative approaches

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *search* a table, then presumably you want `select`:

```
select *
from sessions
where validuntil < current_timestamp;
```

Of course, whether this works or not depends on how your data is stored.

Comment: My guess is that they mean to search the database, and delete all rows matching that search

Comment: @InzeNL . . . I was hoping the OP would clarify.